# Number of questions to attempt to pass a multiple choice test

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-distribution

> There are $100$ multiple choice questions in a test, with $4$ options each.  The probability of choosing a right answer for a question is $0.25$.  Each right answer gets $4$ marks and each wrong answer gets $-1$ mark.  The passing criteria is $50\%$. How many questions should a person attempt to pass the test, given that they are sure of getting at least $30$ questions right.

I tried:
To get $50\%$ (200 marks) in the test,
\begin{align*}
(100 - x)4 -x & = 200\\
400 - 5x & = 200\\
5x & = 200\\
x & = 40 
\end{align*}
incorrect

Should the person attempt $60$ questions to pass the test?

Comment: You have not taken into account the fact that the person is guaranteed of getting at least $30$ questions right or the probability of obtaining a correct answer when the person guesses.

Comment: Conditional probability has entered the chat, take into account the part where you said "sure of getting at least 30 questions right". I would also start by naming some possible events using capital letters and their probabilities; makes it easier to understand and solve

Answer (score 1):

The formulation of the question is a little bit odd to me, since whatever the number of questions the person answers, there is a possibility of failing. Obviously, the person will get $120$ points from the questions they are sure of knowing the answer to, so they need $80$ additional points out of the $70$ other questions. They may answer $20$ questions and luckily get them all correct, or answer $70$ questions and get the all wrong, losing $70$ points. **What we can do is to compute the probability of passing the test as a function of the number of questions answered randomly, and mazimize this probability**

Assume that the person answers randomly $n$ questions, where $0\le n\le 70$ and $Y$ the number of correct answers to these questions. Then $Y$ has a binomial distribution of parameters $n$ and $1/4$. Their score will be

$$X=120 + 4Y + (-1)(n-Y) = 120-n + 5Y$$

so the probability $p(n)$ of passing the test is

$p(n)=P(X\ge 200) = P(120-n+5Y \ge 200) = P(Y \ge 16 + \frac{n}{5})= \sum_{\lceil 16+\frac{n}{5} \rceil}^n \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}$

Using a computer, we see that $p(n)$ is very small for every $n$ and it is maximum when $n=70$ with a whooping $p(70)=0.000824$ probability of passing the test. **They'd better study than rely on luck to pass the exam**.

---

We may also count the average number of points the person will make on the test by answering randomly $n$ questions. Using the notations above, we have $E(Y)=\frac{n}{4}$ so

$$E(X)=120-n+ 5E(Y) = 120 + \frac{n}{4}$$

We have $E(X)\ge 200 \iff n \ge 320$. This explains why the probability of passing the test is extremely low. Intuitively, each time the person answers $4$ questions randomly, they will lose $3$ points and gain $4$ so a net gain of only $1$ point.